# Python Order Dictionary in Chronological Order even if keys are different

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make an RSS feed composed of different sources and I would like them to be sorted by newest date, rather than the source itself. I store all of my news in one python dictionary, regardless of its source:

```
feed = None
    if sports['nhl'] == 1:
        feed = newsParse('nhl')
        allOff = False
    if sports['nba'] == 1:
        feed = newsParse('nba')
        allOff = False
    if sports['nfl'] == 1:
        feed = newsParse('nfl')
        allOff = False
    if sports['mlb'] == 1:
        feed = newsParse('mlb')
        allOff = False
```

The function looks like this:

```
def newsParse(league):
    rss_url = 'https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/' + league + '/news'
    parser = feedparser.parse(rss_url)

    newsInfo = {
        'title': [],
        'link': [],
        'description': [],
        'date': []
    }

    for entry in parser.entries:
        newsInfo['title'].append(entry.title)
        newsInfo['description'].append(entry.description)
        newsInfo['link'].append(entry.links[0].href)
        newsInfo['date'].append(entry.published)
    
    return newsInfo
```

If I print out 'feed' I get all of the titles sorted by source, then all of the descriptions sorted by source, and etc. The ['date'] data looks like this:

```
Fri, 24 Jul 2020 09:35:08 EST'
```

How can I sort all of my values in chronological order, whilst keeping the titles, descriptions, and links together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not save the entries as a list of dictionaries ?

For example:

```
def newsParse(league):
    rss_url = 'https://www.espn.com/espn/rss/' + league + '/news'
    parser = feedparser.parse(rss_url)

    newsInfo = []

    for entry in parser.entries:
        newEntry = {'title': entry.title,
                    'description': entry.description,
                    'link': entry.link,
                    'date': entry.date}
        newsInfo.append(newEntry)
    
    return newsInfo
```

`newsInfo` will be a list of dictionaries,

and you can sort that list using this line of code:

```
sorted(newsInfo, key=lambda k: k['date'])
```

If the date from the RSS feed is a string,

I think you should convert it to python's datetime type for the sorting to work.

**Edit (answer for comment):**

If you need a single list with all the leagues,
you can use this code:

```
feed = []
if sports['nhl'] == 1:
    feed.extend(newsParse('nhl'))
    allOff = False
if sports['nba'] == 1:
    feed.extend(newsParse('nba'))
    allOff = False
if sports['nfl'] == 1:
    feed.extend(newsParse('nfl'))
    allOff = False
if sports['mlb'] == 1:
    feed.extend(newsParse('mlb'))
    allOff = False
```

After feed contains all the data you need,
you can sort it by date:

```
sorted(feed, key=lambda k: k['date'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use feedparser's published_parsed datatype to sort the list without having to use datetime.

Comment: I have run into a new problem. When ever I call my function on feed, it overwrites the previous function and only prints the latest 'league'. How can I make my feed variable one large list containing all of the leagues (nhl, nba, nfl, etc)?

Comment: I edited my answer to include your new question. Basically you need feed to start as an empty list and then call `feed.extend(newList)` to add/concatenate a list into feed.